# Проблема при компиляции библиотеки zlib

Tags: mingw-w64, zlib

Библиотека входит в состав Pangolin. При сборке Pangolin возникает ошибка с библиотекой zlib. Описание ошибки:

```
"C:\Program" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-4.8.5-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin\windres.exe: preprocessing failed.
CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\build.make:60: recipe for target 'zlib1rc.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[5]: *** [zlib1rc.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:111: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/all] Error 2
makefile:139: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [all] Error 2
external\CMakeFiles\__zlib.dir\build.make:110: recipe for target 'external/zlib/src/__zlib-stamp/__zlib-build' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [external/zlib/src/__zlib-stamp/__zlib-build] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:192: recipe for target 'external/CMakeFiles/__zlib.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [external/CMakeFiles/__zlib.dir/all] Error 2
makefile:150: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

Вычитал, что это связано с неправильной работой компилятора windres из MinGW.
Пример, как это полечить описан [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45248034/cmake-generated-mingw-makefile-has-quoting-errors) от автора utopia
Но проблема заключается в том, что в CMakeList уже прописана часть кода, чтобы исправить эту ошибку, а она все равно возникает

У меня есть предположение, что при компиляции, оно не может определить местоположение windres, но как ему указать его местоположение, не понимаю.

Если кто-то знает из-за чего проблема или если моя догадка правильная, тогда как указать правильно путь, прошу подскажите.

MinGW находиться по пути C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-4.8.5-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin
В %PATH% так же прописан этот путь.

Comment: *"В %PATH% так же прописан этот путь."* - не делайте так. Прописывайте везде абсолютные пути в кавычках и все будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Это ошибка в `windres`, который осуществляет вызов программ, но не экранирует пути с пробелами в кавычки. Здесь, например, обсуждается эта проблема: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/27484438-windres-does-not-escape-path-with-spaces-in-them

Самый простой путь решения - установить набор инструментов в каталог без пробелов.